# Query to show customers and their contacts in columns side by side

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure it out if it's possible to achieve something having this tables as example...

```
CustomersTable
 Id  | Name | Address
  1  | John | Street A
  2  | Paul | Street B
  3  | Mary | Street C

ContactsTable
 Id  | CustomerId | ContactName | Contact
  1  |     1      |  Contact A  |   123
  2  |     1      |  Contact B  |   543
  3  |     2      |  Contact 1  |   678
  4  |     3      |  Contact A1 |   980
  5  |     3      |  Contact B2 |   521
```

And get something like this...

```
 Id  |  Name  |  Address   | ContactId_1 | ContactName_1 | Contact_1 | ContactId_2 | ContactName_2 | Contact_2
  1  |  John  |  Street A  |      1      |   Contact A   |    123    |      2      |   Contact B   |    543
  2  |  Paul  |  Street B  |      3      |   Contact 1   |    678    |     NULL    |     NULL      |    NULL
  3  |  Mary  |  Street C  |      4      |   Contact A1  |    980    |      5      |   Contact B2  |    521
```

The idea is to get a table where the contacts are side by side of each customer where it belongs. And the contact columns contacts will depend of course on the number of contacts of each customer.

This can be done? How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you presenting/using this data? It seems like something better done in the presentation layer

Comment: My idea to get the data like this is to filter/search the records. It's something that maybe will be much of a help to me. But because my knowledge of TSQL isn't much and i am not sure if its possible to do this. I am still looking for the best way to search in multiple tables using a unique keyword.

Comment: What you are trying to do there won't help you to search. In fact if you implement that and then try and search you will have a much greater performance impact. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I believe so. What i am trying to achieve is search for a keyword in 3 tables at the same time. It can be anything, a contact, an address, a name, a postal code. And for that reason i am trying to find the best way to search for any match to the keyword in three tables. The tables are the contracts, the second is the holders where each contract can have more than one holder, and the contacts table where each holder have a set of contacts. The problem is search in these three tables for anything that the user is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with both an `UNPIVOT` and a `PIVOT` if you know the number of columns to transform, then you can use a static version:

```
select *
from
(
  select id, customerid, name, address,
    col + '_'+ cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
    value
  from
  (
    select c.id, customerid, c.name, c.address,
      t.contactname,
      cast(t.contact as varchar(20)) contact, 
      cast(t.id as varchar(20)) contactid,
      row_number() over(partition by customerid order by customerid) rn
    from customers c
    left join contacts t
      on c.id = t.customerid
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (ContactName, Contact, ContactId)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  min(value)
  for col in ([ContactId_1], [ContactName_1], [Contact_1],
              [ContactId_2], [ContactName_2], [Contact_2])
) p
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44052/29)

But if you do not know how many contacts a record is going to have, then I would use Dynamic SQL to do this:

```
DECLARE @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SET @colsUnPivot = stuff((select ','
                      +quotename(case when C.name = 'id' then'ContactId' else c.name end)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('contacts') and
               C.name <> 'CustomerId'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @colsPivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(case when C.name = 'id' then'ContactId' else c.name end + '_' + cast(rn as varchar(10)))
         from sys.columns as C
         cross apply
         ( 
           select row_number() over(partition by customerid order by customerid) rn
           from customers c
           left join contacts t
             on c.id = t.customerid
          ) x
         where C.object_id = object_id('contacts') and
               C.name <> 'CustomerId'
         group by name, rn
         order by rn
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


set @query 
  = ' 
      select *
      from
      (
        select id, customerid, name, address,
          col + ''_''+ cast(rn as varchar(10)) col,
          value
        from 
        (
          select c.id, customerid, c.name, c.address,
            t.contactname,
            cast(t.contact as varchar(20)) contact, 
            cast(t.id as varchar(20)) contactid,
            row_number() over(partition by customerid order by customerid) rn
          from customers c
          left join contacts t
            on c.id = t.customerid
        ) x1
        unpivot 
        (
           value
           for col in (' + @colsUnPivot + ')
        ) unpvt 

      ) x2
      pivot
      (
        min(value)
        for col in(' + @colsPivot +')
      )p'

execute(@query)
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44052/47)

Both with produce the same results.

Comment: I don't know the number of columns so i have to go with the dynamic version. I tried your example with my real case and it works in SQL Fiddle. But for some reason that i don't really know, if i execute the query in the sql server it doesn't show any results, it only says 'Command(s) completed successfully'... Why is that?

Comment: @Miguel instead of `execute(@query)` try `print @query` and review the code to be sure there are no errors

Comment: Yes i am getting an error related to a column... It says "The type of column "Description" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.". The Description is the same column of ContactName that i have used in my example. It happens that the Contact column is of type 'int' and Description is of type nvarchar(25). I have some other columns from the customers table but i am casting all to nvarchar(100) but still getting the error. It's strange but i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @Miguel can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the data you are using?

Comment: This is an example of my tables and of the data i have [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abd21/3). The only difference is that it works in the SQL Fiddle but doesn't work in the SQL Server.

Comment: @Miguel what version of sql server?

Comment: @Miguel I am not able to reproduce the error in SQL Server 2012

Comment: No problem. I already understood how to accomplish what i want. I just have to dig up a little bit to find where is the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way is with a join and aggregation.  The key is to generate a sequence number for the pivot:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.address,
       max(case when seqqnum = 1 then con.ContactId end) as ContactId_1,
       max(case when seqqnum = 1 then con.ContactName end) as ContactName_1,
       max(case when seqqnum = 1 then con.Contact end) as Contact_1,
       max(case when seqqnum = 2 then con.ContactId end) as ContactId_2,
       max(case when seqqnum = 2 then con.ContactName end) as ContactName_2,
       max(case when seqqnum = 2 then con.Contact end) as Contact_2
from customers c join
     (select con.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId order by id) as seqnum
      from contacts con
     ) con
     on c.id = con.customerid
group by c.id, c.name, c.address
```

You can also do this with a series of joins, but I prefer this approach.